# In R, which branch does devtools::install("path/to/directory") install?

Tags: r, devtools

When you use the `devtools::install_github` function, it allows you to specify a branch. But `devtools::install` doesn't? I have a local repository that I need to install from that has a few branches. I need to install a specific branch. How can I do that with `devtools::install`?

Comment: `devtools::install` is going to install the branch that is current at the path. If that path has `master` checked out, then ... master. If that path has something else checked out ... you get it. (I tend to use git worktrees, so it's very clear to me which branch I'm `install`-ing.

Comment: Said differently, is installs a *directory*, it has no awareness of the state of the git repo that may (or may not) be within that directory.